# Android unit testing Location not mocked

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, location

I am trying to test my presenter and I need a mocked location, however, I get null or have default values such as 0.0 for lat, long, bearing and so on

I have already tried creating a new Location object and initializing all the fields I need.

```
    val latitude = 37.422
    val longitude = -122.084

    val mockLocation = mock(Location::class.java)
    mockLocation.latitude = latitude
    mockLocation.longitude = longitude

    presenter.loadsAirpots(latitude, longitude)
    presenter.locationChanged(mockLocation)

    System.out.println(mockLocation.latitude)
```

I expect latitude to be 37.422 but the actual output is 0.0

Comment: Why do you mock it using Mockito? You can use it directly like val mockLocation = Location("provider")
            mockLocation.latitude = latitude
            mockLocation.longitude = longitude

Comment: @Billda Hi, I tried that, and I got the same output which is 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock an object the real implementation won't be called.
You are trying to call `setLatitude(latitude)` but it won't change the value.

If you want to mock the object you should do:

```
val mockLocation = mock(Location::class.java)
given(mockLocation.getLatitude()).willReturn(latitude)
given(mockLocation.getLongitude()).willReturn(longitude)
```

Or you could create a real object:

```
val realLocation = Location("provider")
realLocation.latitude = latitude
realLocation.longitude = longitude
```

Comment: It's always null, whenever i try to create a real object for unit testing